# Row editing in ag-grid

Tags: angular

Iam developing a grid application where each row contains an edit button and on click of it it should turn as update/cancel buttons and the entire row should be editable. I had set the gridoptions.edittype as "editable" still not working. Can anyone explain how to approach this

Comment: It can help you https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/ @Krishna

Comment: Thanks @HamzaNeffati Iam also referring the same. But entire row editing on click on a button in that respective row is what Iam really looking for